# Multi object knockout mapping

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/VqenG/

Hoping some knockout.js guru can shed some light on this

I am trying to make the Contact objects go into the contact observable array, which is itself an observable array within the ContactGroup object, but I dont understand how to do this? Is it even possible, or am I approaching it the wrong way? Thanks!

```
var json =  
    {"contactGroups" : [
     {
             "name" : "Contact Group",
             "contact" : [
                     {
                             "name" : "aaaa",
                             "email" : "",
                             "telephone" : "",
                             "mobile" : "",
                             "mail_group" : "",
                             "comment" : ""
                     },
                     {
                             "name" : "bbbb",
                             "email" : "",
                             "telephone" : "",
                             "mobile" : "",
                             "mail_group" : "",
                             "comment" : ""
                     },
                     {
                             "name" : "cccc",
                             "email" : "",
                             "telephone" : "",
                             "mobile" : "",
                             "mail_group" : "",
                             "comment" : ""
                     }
             ]
     }
 ]}



function TechnicalViewModel(){
    self = this;

    var ContactGroups = ko.utils.arrayMap(json.contactGroups, function(item) {
        var group = new ContactGroup(item);
        var contacts = ko.utils.arrayMap(item.contact, function(item) {
        return new Contact(item)
        });
        group.contact(contacts)
        return group;
    })
    self.contactGroups(ContactGroups)

    function ContactGroup(data){
        var self = this;

        self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
        self.contact = ko.observableArray([]);

        function Contact(data){
            this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
            this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
            this.telephone = ko.observable(data.telephone);
            this.mobile = ko.observable(data.mobile);
            this.mail_group = ko.observable(data.mail_group);
            this.comment = ko.observable(data.comment);
        }    
    }
}

TechnicalView = new TechnicalViewModel
ko.applyBindings(TechnicalView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move your `Contact` function outside of the `ContactGroup` function. It's scope is limited within the `ContactGroup` function and is not able to be seen by the `ko.utils.arrayMap` function. Moving it outside increases the scope to the entire `TechnicalViewModel`.

```
function TechnicalViewModel(jsonData){
    self = this;

    var ContactGroups = ko.utils.arrayMap(jsonData.contactGroups, function(item) {
        var group = new ContactGroup(item);
        var contacts = ko.utils.arrayMap(item.contact, function(item) {
            return new Contact(item)
        });
        group.contact(contacts)
        return group;
    });

    self.contactGroups = ko.observableArray(ContactGroups);

    function Contact(data) {
        this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
        this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
        this.telephone = ko.observable(data.telephone);
        this.mobile = ko.observable(data.mobile);
        this.mail_group = ko.observable(data.mail_group);
        this.comment = ko.observable(data.comment);
    }

    function ContactGroup(data){
        var self = this;

        self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
        self.contact = ko.observableArray([]);
    }
}

var technicalVM = new TechnicalViewModel(json);
ko.applyBindings(technicalVM);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VqenG/3/

Comment: Thanks ever so much! Need to brush up on my scope!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VqenG/2/) and at [ko.mapping.fromJS](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

ko.mapping.formJS allows to do that :

```
function Contact(data){
     this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
     this.email = ko.observable(data.email);
     this.telephone = ko.observable(data.telephone);
     this.mobile = ko.observable(data.mobile);
     this.mail_group = ko.observable(data.mail_group);
     this.comment = ko.observable(data.comment);
 }
```

in one line :

```
function Contact(data){
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
 }
```

ko.mapping.fromJS is also powerfull when you want to refresh the viewmodel based on new data from server.

I hope it helps.